# arguments file to gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

On Linux, is there a way to pass arguments to gcc from a file. That is to gave file like compile.args

```
% cat compile.args
-g3
-ggdb
 -pedantic
 -pedantic-errors
 -Wall
 -Werror
 -O0
 vec1.cpp
 -o vec1
```

and then give this file to g++/gcc. I can do this using cat compile.args | xargs g++, is they any other way? Does gcc support this?

thanks.

Comment: Sorry, question on linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just run `gcc @compile.args`

Answer (score 1):

For verbosity, also something like this should work (depending on running shell)

```
g++ `cat compiler.args|xargs`
```

or

```
COMPILE_ARGS=`cat compiler.args|xargs` g++ ${COMPILE_ARGS}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to run the output of cat through xargs? It works fine without.

Comment: 1) Habit and 2) explicit removal of linefeeds. =)

Comment: Why would you do this when gcc already has direct support for doing this via the `@` command line option ?

Comment: Because people do use other compilers too than gcc and having or atleast knowledge of how to archive the same functionality will help in porting and/or writing build scripts that would be easier to port. More people do know about shell expansion than gcc commandline options and i sorta thought that stackoverflow is about gaining and sharing knowledge ..